# Express provides me with an empty array. Push is called in an ipfs function. Log works fine

Tags: node.js, express, ipfs

```
router.post('/up', verify, async (req, res) => {
if (req.files.upload.length > 0) {
    var result = [];
    
    req.files.upload.forEach((uploadFile) => {
        ipfs.add(Buffer.from(uploadFile.data), function (err, upfile) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                // THIS WORK
                console.log({ "name": uploadFile.name, "cid": upfile[0].path });

                // THIS NOT
                result.push({ "name": uploadFile.name, "cid": upfile[0].path });
            }
        })
    });

    res.send(result);
}});
```

I get an empty result. How can I fix it? And what is the reason? I don't really understand it ...

Comment: Your code works fine, nothing is wrong with `result.push`, Since `ipfs.add` is async, `res.send` doesn't wait for it's execution and sends the empty result array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async `ipfs.add` function you are calling inside the loop is asynchronous. So `res.send()` is executed *before* those calls come back.

Here's an example of an async approach to execute the multiple `ipfs.add` calls in parallel (or at least parallelish), while gathering the results into a single array.

```
(async () => {

  const content = [ 
    'a', 'b', 'c' 
  ]

  const results = await Promise.all(
    content.map(async (item) => await ipfs.add(item))
  )

  console.log(results)
})()
```

So with your code, something like this - although you need to add error checking back in and format the return object as you had before. Map function expanded for readability.

```
const result = await Promise.all(
  req.files.upload.map(async (uploadFile) => {
    return await ipfs.add(Buffer.from(uploadFile.data));
  })
)

res.send(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot ;)

Comment: @Kyrill great, I'm glad! Please mark it answered :D